# How to create two AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer from one AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have `AVCaptureSession`, I display `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` in `UICollectionViewCell`. If a user clicks on `UICollectionViewCell`, then opens another `CameraController` (it was the heir of `UIViewController`) and there I add `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` in `UIView` animation. When the user closes `CameraController`, the animation is done and I return to `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` in `UICollectionViewCell`, the problem is that while returning noticeably I changed `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` frame. So I want to make two `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, with different frame values. How can I do that?